# list.append() does not appear to work correctly

Tags: python, list, function, append, coordinates

I have created a python function, which should take a series of 3D co-ordinates and place them in a list (within a list).

However when I print out `coord_list`, it doesn't appear to append correctly, for example when these co-ordinates are entered :

```
[1,2,3]

[2,3,4]

[3,4,5]
```

The output of coord_list finally (ignoring the 'q') will be: `[[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5]]`.

Why does it not append correctly, and how can this be fixed?

```
def coords() :

    xyz_list = []
    coord_list = []

    while 1 :
        xyz = raw_input("Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: ")
        xyz = str(xyz)

        del xyz_list[:]

        for num in xyz.split(","):
            xyz_list.append(num)

        print xyz_list

        if xyz[0] != 'q' :
            coord_list.append(xyz_list)
            print coord_list
        else :
            break

coords()
```

Comment: I tested your script and it's OK.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "Why does it not append correctly"?  What do you think it should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `del` which accesses the managed heap. New objects (the members of `xyz_list`) appear on the same spot because the containing list is not deleted. So the list members replace the previous ones in-place and the reference in `coord_list` will point to the new values.

Reproduction in python 2.7.9 (Linux):

```
$ python coords.py

Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 1,2,3
['1', '2', '3']
[['1', '2', '3']]
Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 2,3,4
['2', '3', '4']
[['2', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', '4']]
Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 3,4,5
['3', '4', '5']
[['3', '4', '5'], ['3', '4', '5'], ['3', '4', '5']]
```

I made a small change to the script: `del xyz_list[:]` --> `xyz_list = []`.

Now it works:

```
$ python coords.py

Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 1,2,3
['1', '2', '3']
[['1', '2', '3']]
Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 2,3,4
['2', '3', '4']
[['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '3', '4']]
Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 3,4,5
['3', '4', '5']
[['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['3', '4', '5']]
```

Comment: Thank you, a simple error can drive you crazy sometimes

Answer (score 2):

This is because `coord_list` is storing `[xyz_list, xyz_list, ...]`. You are updating `xyz_list` in each iteration which is in turn being updated in `coord_list`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `del` and clear the list `xyz_list` after adding it to `coord_list`:

```
def coords() :

    xyz_list = []
    coord_list = []

    while 1 :
        xyz = raw_input("Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: ")
        xyz = str(xyz)

        for num in xyz.split(","):
            xyz_list.append(num)

        print xyz_list

        if xyz[0] != 'q' :
            coord_list.append(xyz_list)
            print coord_list
            xyz_list = []
        else :
            break

coords()
```

Output:

```
Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 1,2,3
['1', '2', '3']
[['1', '2', '3']]
Enter co-ordinates (x,y,z) enter 'q' when done: 4,5,6
['4', '5', '6']
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following expression:

```
del xyz_list[:]
```

with:

```
xyz_list = []
```